# Getting error When dt.value length is < 4

Tags: asp.net

I have this code which works fine as long as as dt.Value is different to "int".

This is the line which errors:

```
(dt.Value.ToLower().Substring(0, 4).Equals("date"))
```

It works fine if dt.Value is varchar or datetime.
I provided my suggested solution at the end of this post.

```
            // Edit

            if (e.CommandName == "Edit")

            {

                // Get the item

                RepeaterItem Item = ((RepeaterItem)((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);



                // Get buttons and repeater

                Button savebtn = (Button)(Item.FindControl("btnSave"));

                Button editbtn = (Button)(Item.FindControl("btnEdit"));

                Repeater rFields = (Repeater)(Item.FindControl("repFields"));


                // Enable my fields

                foreach (RepeaterItem RI in rFields.Items)

                {

                    // Get data type

                    HiddenField dt = (HiddenField)(RI.FindControl("hdnDBDataType"));



                    // Set controls

                    if (RI.FindControl("chkSetting").Visible) ((CheckBox)RI.FindControl("chkSetting")).Enabled = true;

                    if (RI.FindControl("ddlSetting").Visible) ((DropDownList)RI.FindControl("ddlSetting")).Enabled = true;

                    if (RI.FindControl("txtSetting").Visible)

                    {

                        ((TextBox)RI.FindControl("txtSetting")).Enabled = true;


                        // Check my data type

                        if (dt.Value.ToLower().Substring(0, 4).Equals("date")) ((CalendarExtender)RI.FindControl("extDateTime")).Enabled = true;

                    }

                }

            }
```

Is this a good fix ? TIA

```
if(dt.Value != "int" && dt.Value.ToLower().Substring(0, 4).Equals("date"))
```

Comment: `dt.Value.StartsWith("date", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` ← Use StartsWith and use a case and culture insensitive comparison instead.

Answer (score 1):

Substring will throw an error if the second parameter is higher than the lenght of the string. What you need to do is check the length before doing the substring or use a method like @Igor suggested in the comments.

Your suggestion to check != "int" is not fullproof if let's say somehow the value is any string less than 4 characters.

```
(dt.Value.Length > 3 && dt.Value.ToLower().Substring(0, 4).Equals("date"))
```

I will also put @Igor suggestion here because it is also fullproof:

```
(dt.Value.StartsWith("date", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```